# EF Core Multiple Entities have a property of a common type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following schema (abbreviated to relevant code)

```cs
class Person
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public ICollection<MetaData> MetaData {get;set;}
}
class Car
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Make {get;set;}
  public ICollection<MetaData> MetaData {get;set;}
}
class Building
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Address {get;set;}
  public ICollection<MetaData> MetaData {get;set;}
}
class MetaData
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string CLRType {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}

  // These two fields together form a connection to the other entities
  public int Key {get;set;} // the PK of the connected entity
  public string Type {get;set;} // nameof(Entity)
}
```

How can I represent this in EF Core?

Using `OwnsMany` create a table per type+metadata type connection
If I try using TPH, then the metadata table ends up with additional fields per connected entity

Neither of those solutions are ideal for me.
I do not need restraints in the database, I just want a way to express this relation in such a way that EF Core will be able to hydrate my models
Even if I have to provide the sql manually (even for both reads and writes) that would be workable

If this is not possible with the existing APIs provided, is there a way I can write extensions on my own that will do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two forms of relations.
You can either have type safe relations and replicate the foreign keys on your Metadata class (don't forget to add unique constraints)

```
class MetaData
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string CLRType {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
  public int PersonId {get;set;}
  public Person Person {get;set;}
  public int CarId {get;set;}
  public Car Car {get;set;}
  public int BuildingId {get;set;}
  public Person Building {get;set;}
}
```

Or keep it loosely coupled and do the joins by hand

```
class Car
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Make {get;set;}
}

// not mapped in the database, just used for display purposes
class CarViewModel 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Make {get;set;}
}




var carIds = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

// we use 2 contexts here so we can query both tables at the same time.
// otherwise Task.WhenAll(...) would throw an exception.
// you should also disable change tracking to improve speed.
var carsTask = context1.Cars
    .Where(c => carIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .ToListAsync();
var metadataTask = context2.Metadata
    .Where(m => carIds.Contains(m.Key) && m.Type == "Car")
    .GroupBy(m => m.Key)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

await Task.WhenAll(carsTask, metadataTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

var cars = carsTask.Result
    .Select(c => new CarViewModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Make = c.Make,
        Metadata = metadataTask.Result.TryGetValue(c.Id, out var m) ? m : Array.Empty<Metadata>(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or have separate tables for the metadata

```
abstract class MetaData
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string CLRType {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}

class CarMetaData : MetaData
{
  public int CarId {get;set;}
  public Car Car {get;set;}
}

class Car
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Make {get;set;}
  public ICollection<CarMetaData> MetaData {get;set;}
}
```

Which version suits you best is up to your and your specific business needs.

Comment: The solution of using a ViewModel is the closest to where I am trying to go, but I am/was hoping there is way to configure/extend EF to do that for me. 

I don't mind going down the rabbit hole to write the extension, but I'd like to know that it is at all possible first